# How to stop viewport camera from moving when exiting other cameras after moving them

Tags: 3d-view

I use fly mode to navigate around in Blender, and when pressing  <kbd>0</kbd> to enter and exit cameras, the viewport camera returns to the same place. But as soon as a camera is moved, the viewport camera resets to the 3D cursor. Is there any way to fix this?

This is what happens when you don't move the camera
[image: viewport without moving camera]

[image: entering camera]
And this is what happens when you do
[image: entering and moving camera]
[image: moves the viewport camera]

It moves the viewport camera to the 3D cursor. Hope this makes sense what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I cannot reproduce this. How you move the camera? Grab? Key frames? Do you move it while flying around? There is an add-on called "Stored Views" that comes with Blender. With it you can store the current viewport's point of view. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: @Blunder I move the camera by pressing numpad 0 to go into its view, entering fly mode and then moving around to a different position. Then when I exit the camera view by pressing numpad 0, the viewport camera has changed. I added "Stored Views" but it doesn't seem to do anything.